How can I list files with a specific sample rate or bit depth?
I'm looking for someone to help me create a bash script using the mediainfo tool to loop through my entire audio library and output a list of .flac files that do not have a Sampling rate of "44.1 kHz" or a Bit depth of "16 bits".
I gave it a shot, but it doesn't run. Here's where my head was at.
#!/usr/bin/env sh
mediainfo /media/Media/Music/ 
if grep ["Bit depth" != "16"] || ["Sampling rate" != "44.1 kHz"]
then
    echo "$flacfile"
    echo mediainfo /media/Media/Music/ | grep 'Bit depth'
    echo mediainfo /media/Media/Music/ | grep 'Sampling rate'
else
    # do nothing...
fi


There is some error in your script: You are using grep wrongly, there is no loop on .flac file, mediainfo is not stored, and the pipes are used wrongly.
With mediainfo you could do something like that:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MUSIC_DIR="/media/Media/Music"

find "$MUSIC_DIR" -type f -iname "*.flac" | while read -r flacfile; do
    bit_depth=$(mediainfo --Output="Audio;%BitDepth%" "$flacfile")
    sample_rate=$(mediainfo --Output="Audio;%SamplingRate_String%" "$flacfile")

    if [ "$bit_depth" != "16" ] || [ "$sample_rate" != "44.1 kHz" ]; then
        echo "File: $flacfile"
        echo "Bit depth: $bit_depth"
        echo "Sampling rate: $sample_rate"
        echo
    fi
done


Thank you for the solution. I see what I did wrong here. I appreciate the help! :D

I just noticed, "44.1 KHz" should have a lower case K (kHz). Thanks again.
